# in vb.net I want to loop charts

Tags: vb.net

I want listbox1 item =

```
aa
ab
ac
ba
bb
bc
ca
cb
cc
```

And this my code

```
Dim text As String = "abc"
Dim i As Integer = 0

Do
    ListBox1.Items.Add(text.Chars(i))
    i += 1
Loop Until (i = text.Length)
```

Comment: You got the first character part done. Just do a second loop inside the first. Or you can view this a counting in base 3.

Comment: I do that but come me error

Comment: I new in programing :(

Comment: Can you should what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this, you need 2 loops:

```
For i as Integer = 0 to 2
    For j as Integer = 0 to 2
        ListBox1.Items.Add(text.Chars(i) & text.Chars(j))
    Next
Next
```